# How to convert this Python code which uses genetic algorithm to calculate the best path into MMA

Tags: mathematical-optimization, python

> [Question:](https://github.com/zhongxiaolong1988/GeneticAlgorithm)
>   From a logistics center, multiple distribution vehicles are used to deliver goods to multiple customers. Each customer's location and demand for goods are certain, each distribution vehicle's load is certain, and its maximum driving distance for primary distribution is certain. It is required to reasonably arrange the vehicle distribution route to optimize the objective function and meet the following conditions:
>
> (1) The total demand of each customer on each distribution path shall not exceed the load capacity of distribution vehicles;
>
> (2) The length of each distribution path shall not exceed the maximum driving distance of one distribution vehicle;
>
> (3) Each customer's needs must be met and can only be delivered by one distribution vehicle.
>
> Specific examples:
>
> There are two distribution vehicles in a logistics center, with a load capacity of 8t. The maximum driving distance of each vehicle distribution is 50km. See array `d` for the distance $d_{ij}$ between the distribution center (its number is 0) and 8 customers and the distance $d_{ij}$ between 8 customers, and the goods demand $qj$ (I, J = 1, 2,..., 8) of 8 customers. It is required to arrange vehicle distribution route reasonably to minimize the total mileage of distribution.

I know this is a very annoying problem, but I want to convert this [Python code](https://github.com/zhongxiaolong1988/GeneticAlgorithm) that uses genetic algorithm to calculate the best path into MMA **Or** give a post or link using genetic algorithm of MMA to calculate the optimal path arrangement similar to this Python example .

```python
    # -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

    """
    问题：

    从某物流中心用多台配送车辆向多个客户送货,每个客户的位置和货物需求量一定,每台配送车辆的载重量一定,其一次配送的最大行驶距离一定,要求合理安排车辆配送路线,使目标函数得到优化,并满足以下条件:

    (1) 每条配送路径上各客户的需求量之和不超过配送车辆的载重量;

    (2) 每条配送路径的长度不超过配送车辆一次配送的最大行驶距离;

    (3) 每个客户的需求必须满足,且只能由一台配送车辆送货。

    以配送总里程最短为目标函数
    """

    """
    一个实例：

    某物流中心有2 台配送车辆,其载重量均为8t ,车辆每次配送的最大行驶距离为50km ,配送中心(其编号为0) 与8 个客户之间及8 个客户相互之间的距离dij 、8 个客户的货物需求量qj (i 、j = 1 ,2 , ⋯,8) 均见表1 。要求合理安排车辆配送路线,使配送总里程最短。
    采用以下参数:群体规模取20 ,进化代数取25 ,交叉概率取0.9 ,变异概率取0.09 ,变异时基因换位次数取5 , 对不可行路径的惩罚权重取100km ,实施爬山操作时爬山次数取20 。对实例随机求解10 次。

    """

    import random

    #遗传算法
    class GeneticAlgorithm:

        #-----------初始数据定义---------------------
        #定义一个9 * 9的二维数组表示配送中心(编号为0)与8个客户之间，以及8个客户相互之间的距离d[i][j]
        d = [[0, 4, 6, 7.5, 9, 20, 10, 16, 8],              #配送中心（编号为0）到8个客户送货点的距离
             [4, 0, 6.5, 4, 10, 5, 7.5, 11, 10],            #第1个客户到配送中心和其他8个客户送货点的距离
             [6, 6.5, 0, 7.5, 10, 10, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5],       #第2个客户到配送中心和其他8个客户送货点的距离
             [7.5, 4, 7.5, 0, 10, 5, 9, 9, 15],
             [9, 10, 10, 10, 0, 10, 7.5, 7.5, 10 ],
             [20, 5, 10, 5, 10, 0, 7, 9, 7.5],
             [10, 7.5, 7.5, 9, 7.5, 7, 0, 7, 10],
             [16, 11, 7.5, 9, 7.5, 9, 7, 0, 10],
             [8, 10, 7.5, 15, 10, 7.5, 10, 10, 0]];

        # 8个客户分布需要的货物的需求量，第0位为配送中心自己
        q = [0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 2, 2];

        #定义一些遗传算法需要的参数
        JCL = 0.9   #遗传时的交叉率
        BYL = 0.09  #遗传时的变异率
        JYHW = 5    #变异时的基因换位次数
        PSCS = 20   #爬山算法时的迭代次数

        def __init__(self, rows, times, mans, cars, tons, distance, PW):
            self.rows = rows                            #排列个数
            self.times = times                          #迭代次数
            self.mans = mans                            #客户数量
            self.cars = cars                            #车辆总数
            self.tons = tons                            #车辆载重
            self.distance = distance                    #车辆一次行驶的最大距离
            self.PW = PW                                #当生成一个不可行路线时的惩罚因子

        #-------------遗传函数开始执行---------------------
        def run(self):

            print "开始迭代"

            #路线数组
            lines = [[0 for i in range(self.mans)] for i in range(self.rows)]

            #适应度
            fit = [0 for i in range(self.rows)]

            # print "初始输入获取rows个随机排列，并且计算适应度"
            #初始输入获取rows个随机排列，并且计算适应度
            j = 0
            for i in range(0, self.rows):
                j = 0
                while j < self.mans:
                    num = int(random.uniform(0, self.mans)) + 1
                    if self.isHas(lines[i], num) == False:
                        lines[i][j] = num
                        j += 1

                #计算每个线路的适应度
                # print "计算每个线路的适应度 i = %d" % (i)
                fit[i] = self.calFitness(lines[i], False)

            #迭代次数
            t = 0

            while t < self.times:

                #适应度
                newLines = [[0 for i in range(self.mans)] for i in range(self.rows)]
                nextFit = [0 for i in range(self.rows)]
                randomFit = [0 for i in range(self.rows)]
                totalFit = 0
                tmpFit = 0

                # print "计算总的适应度"
                #计算总的适应度
                for i in range(self.rows):
                    totalFit += fit[i]

                # print "通过适应度占总适应度的比例生成随机适应度"
                #通过适应度占总适应度的比例生成随机适应度
                for i in range(self.rows):
                    randomFit[i] = tmpFit + fit[i] / totalFit
                    tmpFit += randomFit[i]

                # print "上一代中的最优直接遗传到下一代"
                #上一代中的最优直接遗传到下一代
                m = fit[0]
                ml = 0

                for i in range(self.rows):
                    if m < fit[i]:
                        m = fit[i]
                        ml = i

                for i in range(self.mans):
                    newLines[0][i] = lines[ml][i]

                nextFit[0] = fit[ml]

                # print "对最优解使用爬山算法促使其自我进化"
                #对最优解使用爬山算法促使其自我进化
                self.clMountain(newLines[0])

                # print "开始遗传"
                #开始遗传
                nl = 1
                while nl < self.rows:
                    #根据概率选取排列
                    r = int(self.randomSelect(randomFit))

                    #判断是否需要交叉，不能越界
                    if random.random() < self.JCL and nl + 1 < self.rows:
                        fline = [0 for x in range(self.mans)]
                        nline = [0 for x in range(self.mans)]

                        #获取交叉排列
                        rn = int(self.randomSelect(randomFit))

                        f = int(random.uniform(0, self.mans))
                        l = int(random.uniform(0, self.mans))

                        min = 0
                        max = 0
                        fpo = 0
                        npo = 0

                        if f < l:
                            min = f
                            max = l
                        else:
                            min = l
                            max = f

                        # print "将截取的段加入新生成的基因"
                        #将截取的段加入新生成的基因
                        """
                        除排在第一位的最优个体外,另N - 1 个个体要按交叉概率Pc 进行配对交叉重组。
                        采用类OX法实施交叉操作,现举例说明其操作方法: 
                        ①随机在父代个体中选择一个交配区域,如两父代个体及交配区域选定为:A = 47| 8563| 921 ,B = 83| 4691|257 ;
                        ②将B 的交配区域加到A 的前面,A 的交配区域加到B 的前面,得:A’= 4691| 478563921 ,B’=8563| 834691257 ;
                        ③在A’、B’中自交配区域后依次删除与交配区相同的自然数,得到最终的两个体为:A”= 469178532 ,B”= 856349127 

                        """
                        while min < max:
                            fline[fpo] = lines[rn][min]
                            nline[npo] = lines[r][min]

                            min += 1
                            fpo += 1
                            npo += 1

                        for i in range(self.mans):
                            if self.isHas(fline, lines[r][i]) == False:
                                fline[fpo] = lines[r][i]
                                fpo += 1

                            if self.isHas(nline, lines[rn][i]) == False:
                                nline[npo] = lines[rn][i]
                                npo += 1

                        #基因变异
                        self.change(fline)
                        self.change(nline)

                        # print "交叉并且变异后的结果加入下一代"
                        #交叉并且变异后的结果加入下一代
                        for i in range(self.mans):
                            newLines[nl][i] = fline[i]
                            newLines[nl + 1][i] = nline[i]

                        nextFit[nl] = self.calFitness(fline, False)
                        nextFit[nl + 1] = self.calFitness(nline, False)

                        nl += 2
                    else:
                        # print "不需要交叉的，直接变异，然后遗传到下一代"
                        #不需要交叉的，直接变异，然后遗传到下一代

                        line = [0 for i in range(self.mans)]
                        i = 0
                        while i < self.mans:
                            line[i] = lines[r][i]
                            i += 1

                        #基因变异
                        self.change(line)

                        #加入下一代
                        i = 0
                        while i < self.mans:
                            newLines[nl][i] = line[i]
                            i += 1

                        nextFit[nl] = self.calFitness(line, False)
                        nl += 1

                # print "新的一代覆盖上一代 当前是第 %d 代" %(t)
                #新的一代覆盖上一代
                for i in range(self.rows):
                    for h in range(self.mans):
                        lines[i][h] = newLines[i][h]

                    fit[i] = nextFit[i]

                t += 1

            #上代中最优的为适应函数最小的
            m = fit[0]
            ml = 0

            for i in range(self.rows):
                if m < fit[i]:
                    m = fit[i]
                    ml = i

            print "迭代完成"
            #输出结果:
            self.calFitness(lines[ml], True)

            print "最优权值为: %f" %(m)
            print "最优结果为:"

            for i in range(self.mans):
                print "%d," %(lines[ml][i]),

            print "    "
            print "    "
            print "    "


        #-----------------遗传函数执行完成--------------------

        #-----------------各种辅助计算函数--------------------
        #线路中是否包含当前的客户
        def isHas(self, line, num):
            for i in range(0, self.mans):
                if line[i] == num:
                    return True
            return False


        #计算适应度,适应度计算的规则为每条配送路径要满足题设条件，并且目标函数即 车辆行驶的总里程越小，适应度越高
        def calFitness(self, line, isShow):

            carTon = 0  #当前车辆的载重
            carDis = 0  #当前车辆行驶的总距离
            newTon = 0
            newDis = 0
            totalDis = 0

            # ll = []
            r = 0       #表示当前需要车辆数
            # l = 0
            fore = 0    #表示正在运送的客户编号
            M = 0       #表示当前的路径规划所需要的总车辆和总共拥有的车辆之间的差，如果大于0，表示是一个失败的规划，乘以一个很大的惩罚因子用来降低适应度

            #遍历每个客户点
            for i in range(0, self.mans):
                #行驶的距离
                newDis = carDis + self.d[fore][line[i]]

                #当前车辆的载重
                newTon = carTon + self.q[line[i]]

                #如果已经超过最大行驶距离或者超过车辆的最大载重，切换到下一辆车
                if newDis + self.d[line[i]][0] > self.distance or newTon > self.tons:
                    #下一辆车
                    totalDis += carDis + self.d[fore][0]  #后面加这个d[fore][0]表示需要从当前客户处返程的距离
                    r += 1
                    fore = 0
                    i -= 1  #表示当前这个点的配送还没有完成
                    carTon = 0
                    carDis = 0
                else:
                    carDis = newDis
                    carTon = newTon
                    fore = line[i]

            #加上最后一辆车的距离和返程的距离
            totalDis += carDis + self.d[fore][0]

            if isShow:
                print "总行驶里程为: %.1fkm" %(totalDis)
            else:
                # print "中间过程尝试规划的总行驶里程为: %.1fkm" %(totalDis)
                pass

            #判断路径是否可用，所使用的车辆数量不能大于总车辆数量
            if r - self.cars + 1 > 0:
                M = r - self.cars + 1

            #目标函数，表示一个路径规划行驶的总距离的倒数越小越好
            result = 1 / (totalDis + M * self.PW)

            return result


        #爬山算法
        def clMountain(self, line):
            oldFit = self.calFitness(line, False)

            i = 0
            while i < self.PSCS:
                f = random.uniform(0, self.mans)
                n = random.uniform(0, self.mans)

                self.doChange(line, f, n)

                newFit = self.calFitness(line, False)

                if newFit < oldFit:
                    self.doChange(line, f, n)
                i += 1

        #基因变异
        #变异的意思是当满足变异率的条件下，随机的两个因子发生多次交换，交换次数为变异迭代次数规定的次数
        def change(self, line):
            if random.random() < self.BYL:
                i = 0
                while i < self.JYHW:
                    f = random.uniform(0, self.mans)
                    n = random.uniform(0, self.mans)

                    self.doChange(line, f, n)
                    i += 1


        #将线路中的两个因子执行交换
        def doChange(self, line, f, n):

            tmp = line[int(f)]
            line[int(f)] = line[int(n)]
            line[int(n)] = tmp

        #根据概率随机选择的序列
        def randomSelect(self, ranFit):

            ran = random.random()

            for i in range(self.rows):
                if ran < ranFit[i]:
                    return i


    #-------------入口函数，开始执行-----------------------------

    """
    输入参数的的意义依次为

            self.rows = rows                            #排列个数
            self.times = times                          #迭代次数
            self.mans = mans                            #客户数量
            self.cars = cars                            #车辆总数
            self.tons = tons                            #车辆载重
            self.distance = distance                    #车辆一次行驶的最大距离
            self.PW = PW                                #当生成一个不可行路线时的惩罚因子

    """
    ga = GeneticAlgorithm(rows=20, times=25, mans=8, cars=2, tons=8, distance=50, PW=100)

    for i in range(20):
        print "第 %d 次：" %(i + 1)
        ga.run()
```

The optimization result calculated by Python is: $Total~~distance:58.5km~~~~~~~~Path:{4, 6, 2, 7, 8, 5, 3, 1}$

Comment: you had better translate the comment into english

Comment: besides,you can directly run Python in MMA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A crude answer:

```
d = {{0, 4, 6, 7.5, 9, 20, 10, 16, 8}, {4, 0, 6.5, 4, 10, 5, 7.5, 11, 
    10}, {6, 6.5, 0, 7.5, 10, 10, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5}, {7.5, 4, 7.5, 0, 10,
     5, 9, 9, 15}, {9, 10, 10, 10, 0, 10, 7.5, 7.5, 10}, {20, 5, 10, 
    5, 10, 0, 7, 9, 7.5}, {10, 7.5, 7.5, 9, 7.5, 7, 0, 7, 10}, {16, 
    11, 7.5, 9, 7.5, 9, 7, 0, 10}, {8, 10, 7.5, 15, 10, 7.5, 10, 10, 
    0}};


WeightedAdjacencyGraph[Range[0, 8], d, 
 EdgeLabels -> 
  Flatten[Table[
    i \[UndirectedEdge] j -> 
     Placed[Style[d[[i + 1, j + 1]], Red], 1/5], {i, 0, 8}, {j, 0, 
     8}]], VertexLabels -> "Name"]
q = {0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 2, 2};(*Goods required for each location*)
(*fit[lis_List]:=If[(Total[If[Length[lis[[1]]]>1,Extract[d,Partition[\
lis[[1]]+1,2,1](*Split*)],d[[0+1,1+lis[[1]]//First]]]]<50)&&(Total[If[\
Length[lis[[2]]]>1,Extract[d,Partition[lis[[2]]+1,2,1](*Split*)],d[[0+\
1,1+lis[[2]]//First]]]]<50),If[(Total[q[[lis[[1]]]]]<8)&&(Total[q[[\
lis[[1]]]]]<8),Total[Extract[d,Partition[Flatten[lis],2,1](*Split*)]],\
100],100]*)
fit[lis_List] := 
 If[(Total[Extract[d, Partition[lis[[1]] + 1, 2, 1](*Split*)]] < 
     50) && (Total[
      Extract[d, Partition[lis[[2]] + 1, 2, 1](*Split*)]] < 50), 
  If[(Total[q[[1 + lis[[1]]]]] <= 8) && (Total[q[[1 + lis[[2]]]]] <= 
      8), Total[
    Extract[d, Partition[Flatten[lis] + 1, 2, 1](*Split*)]], 100], 100]
populationinitialization = 
  Table[Map[Prepend[#, 0] &, 
    TakeList[
     RandomSample[Range[1, 8]], {RandomInteger[{1, 7}], UpTo[10]}]], 
   40];
offspringSelection[x_] := Take[(SortBy[x, fit[#] &]), 20]
mutation[list_List] := 
 Module[{variationSites = RandomSample[Range[1, 8], 3]}, {list, 
   list /. Thread[variationSites -> Reverse[variationSites]]}]

Nest[offspringSelection[Flatten[mutation /@ #, 1]] &, 
 offspringSelection[populationinitialization], 200]
fit /@ %


 Out={57.5,57.5,57.5,57.5,57.5,57.5,57.5,57.5,57.5,57.5,57.5,57.5,57.5,57.5,57.5,57.5,57.5,57.5,57.5,57.5}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(*QQ:2636051698*)
d = {{0, 4, 6, 7.5, 9, 20, 10, 16, 8}, {4, 0, 6.5, 4, 10, 5, 7.5, 11, 
   10}, {6, 6.5, 0, 7.5, 10, 10, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5}, {7.5, 4, 7.5, 0, 10, 
   5, 9, 9, 15}, {9, 10, 10, 10, 0, 10, 7.5, 7.5, 10}, {20, 5, 10, 5, 
   10, 0, 7, 9, 7.5}, {10, 7.5, 7.5, 9, 7.5, 7, 0, 7, 10}, {16, 11, 
   7.5, 9, 7.5, 9, 7, 0, 10}, {8, 10, 7.5, 15, 10, 7.5, 10, 10, 0}}
q = {1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 2, 2};
testfun = 
  Function[{x}, 
   Total[d[[##]] & @@@ Partition[Prepend[x + 1, 1], 2, 1]]];
test = If[Total[q[[#[[1]]]]] > 8  || Total[q[[#[[2]]]]] > 8 , 200., 
    len1 = testfun[#[[1]]]; len2 = testfun[#[[2]]]; 
    If[len2 > 50  || len1 > 50, 200., len1 + len2]] &;
cross[lista_, listb_, {r1_, r2_}] :=
 Module[{l2 = lista[[Span @@ r1]],
   l1 = listb[[Span @@ r2]]},
  {TakeList[
    l1~Join~Cases[lista, x_ /; FreeQ[l1, x]], {RandomInteger[{1, 7}], 
     UpTo[9]}],
   TakeList[
    l2~Join~Cases[listb, x_ /; FreeQ[l2, x]], {RandomInteger[{1, 7}], 
     UpTo[9]}]}]
variation[list_, {a_, b_}] := 
 Module[{index = Length /@ list, list1 = Flatten[list]}, 
  list1[[{a, b}]] = list1[[{b, a}]]; TakeList[list1, index]]
g11[xx_] := Module[{a, p1, p2, p3 = RandomReal[]},
  a = SortBy[xx, test];
  a[[-4 ;; -1]] = a[[1 ;; 4]];
  p1 = Partition[RandomSample[Range[5, 20], 6], 2];
  p2 = Map[Sort, RandomInteger[{1, 7}, {3, 2, 2}], {2}];
  MapThread[({a[[#1[[1]]]], a[[#1[[2]]]]} = 
      cross[Flatten[a[[#1[[1]]]]], Flatten[a[[#1[[2]]]]], #2]) &, {p1,
     p2}];

  If[p3 < 
    0.5, (a[[#]] = variation[a[[#]], RandomSample[Range[8], 2]]) &[
    RandomInteger[{1, 20}]]]; a]

ini = Table[
   TakeList[RandomSample[Range[8]], {RandomInteger[{1, 7}], UpTo[9]}],
    20];
Nest[g11, ini, 500] // {#, Map[test, #]} &
```